# Remove sql table after x days

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c++11, c++14

I am looking for a way for my system made in C ++ to remove old sqls tables after 90 days, I searched but did not find anything related.

The names of my tables are generated according to the days, for example **20170323**

Now the way to remove I can not think of anything that can be done

Comment: Use the MySQL Event Scheduler, and write a query that uses `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the logic in C++ and are willing to use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), you could write a function something like this:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <sstream>

void
maybe_remove_table(const std::string& tablename)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    istringstream in{tablename};
    sys_days table_date;
    in >> parse("%Y%m%d", table_date);
    sys_days today = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
    if (table_date < today - days{90})
        remove_table(tablename);
}
```

This function converts the name of the table into a `date::sys_days`, which is a type alias for `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, days>`.  This is just a coarse `time_point`.  Then it gets the current day (as defined by UTC), and compares the date of the table to 90 days prior to the current day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those SQL tables live in a DBMS rather than your own software system - don't bother taking that task into your own code. Use system facilities such as [`cron`](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) and write an appropriate few-line script (e.g. in bash, python or perl) to check for old tables and issue the command to delete them. This is not the kind of task you should bother yourself to custom-code.

and I say this as a Modern C++ enthusiast :-)

**Edit:** On second thought - why do you even *have* per-day tables? I think that's almost certainly a mis-design. That all probably needs to be in the same table, with an extra date column - and possibly some partitioning, or columnar storage, etc.

Comment: I thought about it, but this tool that I'm creating hundreds of people will also use, so I'm looking for a way of the tool itself to do this cleanup in mysql tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a SQL job that does that. Assuming that tables are generated everyday, you can have a job that read table names from sysobjects table. loop through them and convert table name to datetime, then subtract 90 from current date and compare it with datetime you got from table name.